# Spacing Links on a center wrapper

Tags: css

Preface: Experienced coder, VERY new to CSS.

I've designed a website that uses a wrapper and has a horizontal banner that I want to fill with links on the top (Like retail sites that have their categories listed along the top).

I've placed all the links in a `toplink` class, and I have set `position:relative;`. My goal was to position them using `top:` and `left:`, and then space them out by setting all of their padding-left's to a certain degree. It seems when I do that, however, the last 2 links always jumps off the wrapper and moves to the left of the whole wrapper.

Any better ideas on how to implement this? I don't need solutions necessarily, just some ideas on how to move in a better path.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: do you want the links to be spaced out OR to become wider (eg - if the links look like buttons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming some simple markup like this:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

1) To space out links use `text-align:justify` with a pseudo element after it with 100% width

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Fa8Kz/)**

(Resize browser window and also see what happens when you add/remove a list item from the markup)

### CSS

```
#nav {
    text-align: justify;
    min-width: 500px;
}
#nav:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

2) If you're looking for the links to expand/contract - you should use css tables for this

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/cEv5w/1/)**

(Resize browser window and also see what happens when you add/remove a list item from the markup)

### CSS

```
#nav {
    display:table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
#nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 25px;
    background: beige;
    border: 1px solid brown;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The display: inline-block did it for me, thank you! I had no idea about that command.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the `position:relative` and the `top:0; left:0;` stuff and use `float:left` on the anchors instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't `position: relative` or `float: left` to align them horizontally.

Anchors are inline elements so they'll align horizontally anyway. However, you could add some padding to visually separate them.